# Display listview items as % or £ depending on specification

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, listview

I have a group of listview items which is displaying numbers pulled from an SQL Server table.

These numbers are measures of all sorts of business analytics... Market value, market share, stock etc... So there are different types of numbers.

In my SQL Server table, I have a row called "type" which either says £, % or *NULL* depending on what the measure is. How do I format the listview based on this row to show as 14% instead of 0.14 and £100 instead of 100?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Here is an example:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstItems">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <%# GetFormattedValue( Eval("type").ToString(), Eval("val") ) %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code-behind:

```
Protected Function GetFormattedValue(type As String, itemValue As Object) As String
    Select Case type
        Case "£"
            Return String.Format("{0:C}", itemValue)
            Exit Select
        Case "%"
            Return String.Format("{0:P}", itemValue)
            Exit Select
        Case Else
            Return itemValue.ToString()
    End Select
End Function
```